# How can I get the average of a property in a list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this object:

```
public class BtnCountViews
{
    public BtnCountViews()
    {
    }
    public int DayOfYear { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int BtnCount { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is to get the average value of Views from a list of these objects where Month = 5.

Here's where I get the list data:

```
  public static List<BtnCountViews> btnCountViewsList = db2.Query<BtnCountViews>(sql);
```

Comment: `btnCountViewsList.Where(b => b.Month == 5).Average(b => b.Views);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like that;

```
var avg = btnCountViewsList.Where(x => x.Month == 5).Select(x => x.Views).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average();
```

Also I suggest you to use `DefaultIfEmpty` for possible empty sets. Otherwise if `btnCountViewsList` is empty, an exception is throwed.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
var averageViews = btnCountViewsList.Where(x=>x.Month==5) 
                                    .Average(x=>x.Views);
```

Essentially using the `Where` you filter the `BtnCountViews`, in order to get only those that their `Month` is equal to 5 and then using `Average` you get the average value of Views.

Comment: Corrected code in time :)